# Ragged laminate counter edge around under counter sink

Tags: kitchens, sink

Under mounted sink was installed with laminate counter, now laminate edge around sink is fraying and chipping. Can this be fixed? It is a 30 x 16 hole, not sure about the corner radius, too small for standard 30 x 24  stainless steel sink rims.

Comment: Change the countertop or the sink - that was a poor combination of choices. Undermount needs a solid counter, not laminate. Laminate needs a top mount sink. You have the example of why in front of you.

Comment: One of many hack/jerryrigged jobs of previous owner ;(

Comment: A picture might help people come up with some short-term patch it up ideas for you.